# How to highlight a line of text (with colored background) with animation in beamer?

Tags: beamer, mdframed, highlighting, framed, animations

There are several ways to highlight a line of text with colored background in beamer, for example, using `framed` or `mdframed`.

How to animate this highlight, i.e., filling the background color from left to right? (You can use any packages as you will.)

Scenario: You first list a few points, and then (e.g., after a `\pause`) you emphasize one of them by (progressively) highlighting it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{shaded}
    A piece of shaded text with red background for highlight.
  \end{shaded}

  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = yellow]
    A piece of mdframed text with yellow background for highlight.
  \end{mdframed}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `animate`-based version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item on first
    \item<2-> on second
    \alt<3>{\item
      \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{24}
        \multiframe{26}{n=0.0+0.04}{
          \makebox[\widthof{\colorbox{yellow}{on third we see something magical}}][l]{%
            \colorbox{yellow}{\makebox[\n\width][l]{on third we see something magical}}%
          }
        }
      \end{animateinline}
    }{\item<4-> 
      \colorbox{yellow}{on third we see something magical}
    }
    \item<4-> on fourth
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create such an animation with tikz:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\transduration{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \foreach \x in {0,0.01, ...,1}{
    \fill<+>[red] (0,0) rectangle (\x*\textwidth,1);
}
\node[anchor=west] at (0.25,0.5) {A piece of text with red background for highlight.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]